# As a result of processing arrays -nan(ind)

Tags: c

I am writing a program that creates arrays of a given length and manipulates them. You cannot use other libraries.

- First, an array M1 of length N is formed, after which an array M2 of length N is formed/2.
- In the M1 array, the division by Pi operation is applied to each element, followed by elevation to the third power.
- Then, in the M2 array, each element is alternately added to the previous one, and the tangent modulus operation is applied to the result of addition.
- After that, exponentiation is applied to all elements of the M1 and M2 array with the same indexes and the resulting array is sorted by dwarf sorting.
- And at the end, the sum of the sines of the elements of the M2 array is calculated, which, when divided by the minimum non-zero element of the M2 array, give an even number.

The problem is that the result X gives is -nan(ind). I can't figure out exactly where the error is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
const int A = 441;
const double PI = 3.1415926535897931159979635;
 
inline void dwarf_sort(double* array, int size) {
    size_t i = 1;
    while (i < size) {
        if (i == 0) {
            i = 1;
        }
        if (array[i - 1] <= array[i]) {
            ++i;
        }
        else
        {
            long tmp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i - 1];
            array[i - 1] = tmp;
            --i;
        }
    }
}
 
inline double reduce(double* array, int size) {
 
    size_t i;
    double min = RAND_MAX, sum = 0;
 
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (array[i] < min && array[i] != 0) {
            min = array[i];
        }
    }
 
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if ((int)(array[i] / min) % 2 == 0) {
            sum += sin(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
 
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i, N, j;
    double* M1 = NULL, * M2 = NULL, * M2_copy = NULL;
    double X;
    unsigned int seed = 0;
 
    N = atoi(argv[1]); /* N равен первому параметру командной строки */
    M1 = malloc(N * sizeof(double));
    M2 = malloc(N / 2 * sizeof(double));
    M2_copy = malloc(N / 2 * sizeof(double));
 
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
    {
        seed = i;
        srand(i); 
        
        /*generate*/
        for (j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
            M1[j] = (rand_r(&seed) % A) + 1;
        }
 
        for (j = 0; j < N / 2; ++j) {
            M2[j] = (rand_r(&seed) % (10 * A)) + 1;
        }
 
        /*map*/
        for (j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        {
            M1[j] = pow(M1[j] / PI, 3);
        }
 
        for (j = 0; j < N / 2; ++j) {
            M2_copy[j] = M2[j];
        }
 
        M2[0] = fabs(tan(M2_copy[0]));
        for (j = 0; j < N / 2; ++j) {
            M2[j] = fabs(tan(M2[j] + M2_copy[j]));
        }
 
        /*merge*/
        for (j = 0; j < N / 2; ++j) {
            M2[j] = pow(M1[j], M2[j]);
        }
 
        /*sort*/
        dwarf_sort(M2, N / 2);
 
        /*sort*/
        X = reduce(M2, N / 2);
    }
    
    printf("\nN=%d.\n", N); 
    printf("X=%f\n", X);
    return 0;
}
```

Knowledgeable people, does anyone see where my mistake is? I think I'm putting the wrong data types to the variables, but I still can't solve the problem.

Comment: `long tmp = array[i];` : `array[i]` is a `double`. Converting from double to long might result in loss of precision. Didn't you get any compiler warning?

Comment: @Jabberwocky: No, the compiler didn't report anything. Now I changed it to double tmp and still get -nan(ind). For example, at N=7 I get the desired values in X, and at N=10, N=100, N=1000 I get -nan(inf) again.

Comment: `const double PI = 3.1415926535897932384626433;` or simply use `M_PI` if you have it available in your implementation (your last few digits (`...1159979635`) are wrong).

Comment: Compile with `-Wall` to get more warnings.

Comment: 1. Remove the `srand` so you get the same sequene of pseudo random numbers during each run. 2. Check if none of your array indexes ever go out of bounds, for example with asserts. 3. Add printfs of relevant variables at strategic places so you can see what happens and/or use your debugger.

Comment: I bet you get some `inf`s -- numbers that are so large they can't be represented by a `double` -- when you raise M1 to the power of M2. These infinities will give you a domain error in the `sin` function, which makes it return an NaN value. (On my system, `sin(pow(1000.0, 1000.0))` gives `-nan`.)

Comment: @Jabberwocky: The random generator is seeded with the index `i`, so that each of the 100 passes gets fresh values, but different runs of the program are reproducible. Array indexing looks okay, but I'm not sure what the seond half of M1 is for.

Comment: @MOehm you're right I've overlooked this.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the `/* merge */` part with this:

```
/*merge*/
for (j = 0; j < N / 2; ++j) {
  printf("%f %f ", M1[j], M2[j]);
  M2[j] = pow(M1[j], M2[j]);
  printf("%f\n", M2[j]);
}
```

This will print the values and the results of the `pow` operation. You'll see that some of these values are huge resulting in an capacity overflow of `double`.

Something like `pow(593419.97, 31.80)` will not end well.

Comment: Looks like you found a bug. But I can't figure out how to raise array elements to a power and not overflow double?

Comment: `pow(593419.97, 31.80)` is just a really huge number. I have no idea what you're trying to compute here, but do huge numbers like this even make sense for your use case?

Comment: Also consider M Oehm's comment regarding trigonometric functions on huge values.

Comment: In my program, the main thing is to output X, but the task requires manipulating arrays, including exponentiation and sine. Maybe I should change the data types? Do you not know how to solve this overflow problem in order to get a number in X as a result?

Comment: @DmitriiShurygin: Even if your powers of huge numbers could be represented, it wouldn't really help. Sine is cyclic in 2·pi and the accuracy of floating-point numbers is so coarse that you'd really be doing a random sample between −1 and +1. (By the way, if you have a sorted array, the smallest element ist at the beginning.) Does the procedure serve a purpose? To me, it looks more like an esoteric ritual than any real calculation.

Comment: @MOehm: I totally agree. This assignment was given to me in my course of education, and no matter how stupid the requirements look, I need to fulfill them. In general, the essence of all these manipulations is to load my computer with this program and compile it for 1 or more cores, then compare the speed. But the bottom line is that while doing the work on the assignment, I come across an overflow and I have no other way out.

Comment: @DmitriiShurygin maybe you should ask the person (teacher, tutor or whatever) that gave you this assignment for further information. We can't tell you more. On the other hand if the only purpose of your program is just to consume CPU cycles, you can probably just ignore those NaN values.

Comment: Okay, so it's a parallelization exercise. I don't really see a lot of opportunity for simplifying, but tht seems to be on purpose. The tangent function can yield infinite values, too. Perhaps you were meant to calculate m1^(−m2)? That would yield zeros instead of infinities and the results would make more sense as arguments to the sine function. Perhaps you can just leave the NaNs, but you could also test intermediate results with `isnan` from `<math.h>` and ignore them. (By the way, I think you got the "tan" step wrong: Aren't you supposed to add the previous element of m2?)